# Find most compatible NIFI Registry version for NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I wanted to implement version controlling for my existing data flows which were build using NIFI 1.11.4, before starting the integration with the NIFI registry I wanted to know should I need to concern about the compatible versions. so I went through some NIFI and NIFI Registry documentation but unfortunately, I couldn't find any hint about it, hope any suggestions about my problem Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache NiFi 1.11.4 and NiFi Registry 0.6.0

Refer to this for details - https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.5.1/release-notes/content/component_availability_in_hdf.html